# Select all inputs text from body with JQuery

Tags: jquery, selector

I just want to get all the `<input type="text"></input>` from the body of the html.

So far I have this:

```
function toUpper() {
    var elements = $("body input:text");
    for(var i=0; i<elements.lenght; i++){
        elements[i].val(elements[i].val().toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work... I might be missing something on the JQuery Selector... But I don't know what.

Thank you!

Comment: typo: `lenght` -> `length`  --- also use `.each()`: http://api.jquery.com/each/, or in this case, you can actually use `.val()`: http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2 (see the function form)

Answer (score 5):

```
function toUpper() {
    $("input:text").val(function(i, val) {
        return val.toUpperCase();
    });        
}
```

This is probably more convenient.
**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/4yUqL/85/

Comment: +1, good answer, though the other reason the original didn't work is because `elements[i]` returns the unwrapped node.

Comment: hmmm.. I want a big **J** on my shirt please... :)

Comment: @jAndy, haha, a little subtle.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body input:text").each(function(){
         $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is fine, although the `body` part is a bit unnecessary (I hope you don't have any `input`s outside of the body).

But the rest is problematic. When you index a jquery object, you get the actual `HtmlInputElement` (or whatever) object, *not* a jquery wrapper around that object. So you can't use the jquery `.val()` command without first turning it into a jquery object. Here's a corrected version of your current code:

```
var elements = $("input:text");
for(var i = 0; i< elements.length; i++)
    $(elements[i]).val($(elements[i]).val().toUpperCase());
```

But the functional approach suggested by jAndy is a much cleaner way of doing it.